# How to insert_batch() in Codeigniter 3 with "inconsistent?" array associative

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've Googling but the results doesn't match with my problem.

so, i have this array:

```
$data1 = array(
            'DRAWING_NO'=>123,
            'NO_PLANNING'=>321,

        );
$data2 = array(
            'DRAWING_NO'=>456,
            'NO_PLANNING'=>654,
            'ON_CREATE'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
```

then i'm doing insert_batch()

```
$this->db->insert_batch('tb_drawing_lvl',array($data1,$data2));
```

but i got error
[image: error insert]

yes, i knew it, because in $data1 i don't give 'ON_CREATE' key. but i want insert them to my table and the result is like this
[image: result table]

How to do that using insert_batch?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up applying the below logic.

Actually What I did is created a separate array and and went through the loop of the existing array and checked if the necessary key and values exists, if not i have added those keys and performed batch insert with the all the keys required!

```
$data = array(
            array(
                'DRAWING_NO' => 121 ,
                'NO_PLANNING' => 123
            ),
            array(
                'DRAWING_NO'=>456,
                'NO_PLANNING'=>654,
                'ON_CREATE'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            )
        );

        $row_arr = array();

        foreach($data as $row){

            $temp = array(
                'DRAWING_NO' => isset($row['DRAWING_NO']) ? $row['DRAWING_NO'] : NULL,
                'NO_PLANNING' => isset($row['NO_PLANNING']) ? $row['NO_PLANNING'] : NULL,
                'ON_CREATE' => isset($row['ON_CREATE']) ? $row['ON_CREATE'] : date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );

            array_push($row_arr,$temp);
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('test',$row_arr);
```

Comment: @PunitGajjar sorry for late reply.
yeah that really help me, but I'm still curious why insert_batch won't do insert when array doesn't consistent

Comment: @EarthLander, For now can can consider that as a loophole in the query builder.. I still havent tried with the latest version for the same issue.

Comment: @EarthLander I have raised an issue on the CI support! https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/6124

Comment: @EarthLander , check this out (https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5086)